# Using Storybook/vue with SCSS

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, sass, storybook

I've created a project using `vue create` and then installed Storybook. It is running fine, except when I add scss to the component I get the following error:

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (14:0)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| 
| 
> .test {
|   background: red !important;
| }
```

Here's what my component looks like:

```
<template>
    <h1 class="test">Hello</h1>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Test",
    props: {
        msg: String
    },
}
</script>
<style lang="scss" scoped>
  .test {
    background: red !important;
  }
</style>
```

If I remove the `<style>` tag the error will go.

I have followed [the documentation](https://storybook.js.org/docs/configurations/custom-webpack-config/) here for adding `sass` support to `.storybook/main.js` but when I change my config to the following:

```
module.exports = {
  stories: ['../stories/**/*.stories.js'],
  addons: ['@storybook/addon-actions', '@storybook/addon-links'],
  webpackFinal: async (config, { configType }) => {
    // `configType` has a value of 'DEVELOPMENT' or 'PRODUCTION'
    // You can change the configuration based on that.
    // 'PRODUCTION' is used when building the static version of storybook.

    // Make whatever fine-grained changes you need
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.scss$/,
      use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
      include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../'),
    });

    // Return the altered config
    return config;
  },
};
```

I get a new error:

```
Daniels-MBP-2-597b:scss-loader-example dcaine$ npm run storybook

> scss-loader-example@0.1.0 storybook /Users/dcaine/Documents/webdev/test/scss-loader-example
> start-storybook -p 6006

info @storybook/vue v5.3.17
info
info => Loading presets
info => Loading presets
info => Adding stories defined in ".storybook/main.js".
info => Using default Webpack setup.
ERR! ReferenceError: path is not defined
ERR!     at Object.webpackFinal (/Users/dcaine/Documents/webdev/test/scss-loader-example/.storybook/main.js:13:16)
ERR!     at accumulationPromise.then.newConfig (/Users/dcaine/Documents/webdev/test/scss-loader-example/node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/presets.js:261:72)
ERR!     at <anonymous>
ERR!  { ReferenceError: path is not defined
ERR!     at Object.webpackFinal (/Users/dcaine/Documents/webdev/test/scss-loader-example/.storybook/main.js:13:16)
ERR!     at accumulationPromise.then.newConfig (/Users/dcaine/Documents/webdev/test/scss-loader-example/node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/presets.js:261:72)
ERR!     at <anonymous>
ERR!   stack: 'ReferenceError: path is not defined\n    at Object.webpackFinal (/Users/dcaine/Documents/webdev/test/scss-loader-example/.storybook/main.js:13:16)\n    at accumulationPromise.then.newConfig (/Users/dcaine/Documents/webdev/test/scss-loader-example/node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/presets.js:261:72)\n    at <anonymous>' }

WARN Broken build, fix the error above.
WARN You may need to refresh the browser.
```

Comment: Don't know storybook, but i guess it's bundled with webpack. Maybe take a look at that and add the scss loader.

Comment: Thank you, I'd tried that before and it didn't work, but have updated the original post to show my steps

Answer (score 13):

Adding `const path = require('path');` to `.storybook/main.js` solved my issue

Inside `.storybook/main.js`:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  stories: ['../stories/**/*.stories.js'],
  addons: ['@storybook/addon-actions', '@storybook/addon-links'],
  webpackFinal: async (config, { configType }) => {
    // `configType` has a value of 'DEVELOPMENT' or 'PRODUCTION'
    // You can change the configuration based on that.
    // 'PRODUCTION' is used when building the static version of storybook.

    // Make whatever fine-grained changes you need
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.scss$/,
      use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
      include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../'),
    });

    // Return the altered config
    return config;
  },
};
```

Comment: This fixed my issue too.

Answer (score 5):

For my case i used `vue-cli` with everything default to create the project. After i tried adding `lang="scss"`within vue component `style`tag it was giving me error.

According to [Inspecting the Project's Webpack Config](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#inspecting-the-project-s-webpack-config),
As `vue-cli` "abstracts away" webpack config, the `webpack.config.js` file was in `<projectRoot>/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/` for my case.

Now I had to use this config file reference in `.storybook/main.js`

```
const custom = require('../node_modules/@vue/cli-service/webpack.config.js');
module.exports = {
  webpackFinal: (config) => {
    return { ...config, module: { ...config.module, rules:     custom.module.rules } };
  },
};
```

Reference: https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/configure/webpack#using-your-existing-config